# Can't enable input type when checkbox checked (Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery

when checkbox checked , i want input type to be enabled.
i have checked the checkbox but input type still disable.
please help..

this is my jquery

```
$('#haha').change(
  function(id) {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#nama_" + id).prop('disabled', false);
      $("#ket_" + id).prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $("#nama_" + id).prop('disabled', true);
      $("#ket_" + id).prop('disabled', true);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input").focus(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
      });
      $("input").blur(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#lightblue");
      });
    });
  });
```

and here's my checkbox and input type

```
<td> <input type ="checkbox" id="haha" class=checkbox1 name="checklist" value=<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>> <?php echo $agenda->id; ?> </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="dnama" id="nama_<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>" class="yes" value="<?php echo $agenda->nama; ?>" disabled /> </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="dketer" id="ket_<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $agenda->keterangan; ?>" disabled> </td>
```

Comment: You should try to "remove" the property "disabled", not setting it to "false"...

Comment: why dom ready event is defined in change event. it should be opposite of what you are doing

Comment: i changed it, but still same. . i think the problem is here $("#nama_" + id). if my input type name is only "nama_" and $("#nama_" + id) i change into $("#nama_") it works. but i need +id to get different value

Answer (score 0):

First of all use **click** event instead of **change** event for checkbox.

Also why have you kept document.ready statement inside of function.
What I suggest is bring that statement out, and do all event binding inside that.

The problem is that the variable **id** you are using does not have the value you thinking. It has the event object contained in it.
So to get the text elements you can use [type=text] selector.
** Use [type=text] selector only if you have these inputs and checkbox only. In case you have other elements as well, use the appropriate selector.
The code follows as below.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
   }).blur(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#lightblue");
   });

   $('#haha').click(function() {
         if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $("input[type=text]").prop('disabled', false);
         } else {
           $("input[type=text]").prop('disabled', true);
         }
    });
 });
```

Alright for the specific id selectors, I can see from your html that the id comprises of the value of checkbox. So you can use that as well.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
   }).blur(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#lightblue");
   });

   $('#haha').click(function() {
         var id_suffix = $(this).val();
         if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $("input#name_"+id_suffix).prop('disabled', false);
           $("input#ket_"+id_suffix).prop('disabled', false);
         } else {
           $("input#name_"+id_suffix).prop('disabled', false);
           $("input#ket_"+id_suffix).prop('disabled', false);
         }
    });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i clicked checkbox, all of input type will be enabled. I want to enable that I just clicked

Comment: it works, but input type enabled is only first row. .when i unchecked first checkbox and checked next row, input type still disabled. i think the problem is come from $('#haha'). that id can't be same. what should i do?

Comment: Yes you are right. The id of two elements should not be same. Check if you are committing that mistake.

For this You can make selectors specific or search inside the parent for the inputs to be disabled/enabled

Comment: <input type ="checkbox" id="haha" name="checklist" value=<?php echo $agenda->id; ?>> i only have 1 id and different value, how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
function enable(id) {
if(document.getElementById('haha').checked) {
document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled= false;
document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled= false;

}else {
    document.getElementById("nama_"+id).disabled= true;
    document.getElementById("ket_"+id).disabled= true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you have to use remove attribute over prop for removing DISABLED attribute

```
$('#haha').change( function(event) { 
   var id = event.target.id;
   if (this.checked) { 
       $("#nama_" + id).removeAttr('disabled');         $("#ket_" + id).removeAttr('disabled'); 
} else {
  $("#nama_" + id).attr('disabled', true); 
  $("#ket_" + id).attr('disabled', true); 
} 
$(document).ready(function() { $("input").focus(function() { $(this).css("background-color", "yellow"); }); $("input").blur(function() { $(this).css("background-color", "#lightblue"); }); }); });
```

Comment: when checkbox checked i want to input type from disabled into enabled.

Comment: I updated the answer, now it should solve it problem